# Lighter Version of Mean-Value Theorem Involving Directional Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> If $f$ is real-valued and $f'(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u};\mathbf{u})$ exists for $t\in [0,1]$, show there exists a $\theta\in (0,1)$ such that $f(\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{u})-f(\mathbf{c})=f'(\mathbf{c}+\theta \mathbf{u};\mathbf{u})$.

At first I thought maybe I should define an auxliary function with respect to $t$? I was thinking $g(t)=f\circ \gamma$, where $\gamma(t)=(1-t)\mathbf{c}+t(\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{u})$. Then $g(1)-g(0)$ gets me the left result. However, I am not sure this is what is needed.

If the directional derivative exists, does this mean $f'(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u};\mathbf{u})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}D_{k}f(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u})u_{k}$? I don't think I can assume this because $f$ is not assumed differentiable.

A lot of problems are due to the fact that $f$ is not assumed differentiable. How do I apply the Mean-Value Theorem?

Any tips are appeciated on what I should begin doing!

Comment: In your notation, what does $f'(c + tu; u)$ mean precisely?

Comment: It is not necessary that all partial derivatives exist if the directional derivative with respect to $\mathbf{u}$ exists.

Answer (score 4):

This follows directly from the MVT for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and the existence of the directional derivative for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Take $F:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$  where  $F(t) =f(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u})$.  If $F$ is differentiable (as will be shown)  we have by the ordinary MVT for some $\theta \in (0,1),$

$$f(\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{u}) - f(\mathbf{c}) = F(1) - F(0) = F'(\theta)(1-0) = F'(\theta)$$

Existence of the directional derivative implies existence of $F'$ since

$$F'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(t+h)- F(t)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u} +h\mathbf{u})- f(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u})}{h}= f'(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u};\mathbf{u})$$

Thus,

$$f(\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{u}) - f(\mathbf{c})  = F'(\theta) = f'(\mathbf{c}+\theta\mathbf{u};\mathbf{u})$$